# How to load a schema without knowing the target namespace ahead of time?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I am referring to the code below for my XML validation from XSD and from a 
functional point of view it seems to be working fine.

```
var schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
schemas.Add("http://microsoft.com/HealthCare/HL7/2X", xsdFilePath);

Boolean result = true;
xdocXml.Validate(schemas, (sender, e) =>
{
    result = false;
});
```

Now, as you can see I had to specify the schema name explicitly even though this information is self contained in XSD itself. Is there any way to extract that information from the XSD so that I do not have to specifically specify that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply specify `null` for the namespace:

```
var schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
schemas.Add(null, xsdFilePath);
```

From [XmlSchemaSet.Add Method (String, String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hh8b082.aspx):

> targetNamespace
>        Type: System.String
>              The schema `targetNamespace` property, or **null** to use the `targetNamespace` specified in the schema.

Comment: Right, and I'd also point out to OP that it's not the "schema name" as requested but the target namespace that's required; they're not the same in general.